# Inserting large text into blob

Tags: php, sql, blob, firebird

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem for a long time now and nowhere on the internet was I able to find the answer. I have this situation where i need to insert or update a blob field (subtype 1) from a firebird database with php. The problem is that when the text get like really big >36k it will not execute the query. I know line queries are limited to 32k of data and I tried to use parametrized queries in c#, but i was not able to find something to work for me in PHP. Not even close to working.

I tried with `ibase_blob_Create` and so on i tried inserting directly like `Insert into table (blob_value) values (?)`, `ibase_prepare` that and so on. Nothing seems to work for me. Is there some magical way to make this work in php or is it just impossible to get large text into blob from php?

Ive tried using things like:

```
class DBMgmt_Ibase_Blob extends DBMgmt_Generic_Blob
{
var $blob; // resourse link
var $id;
var $database;

function DBMgmt_Ibase_Blob(&$database, $id=null)
{
    $this->database =& $database;
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->blob = null;
}

function read($len)
{
    if ($this->id === false) return ''; // wr-only blob
    if (!($e=$this->_firstUse())) {
        return $e;
    }

    $data = @ibase_blob_get($this->blob, $len);
    if ($data === false) return $this->_setDbError('read');
    return $data;        
}

function write($data)
{
    if (!($e=$this->_firstUse())) return $e;
    $ok = @ibase_blob_add($this->blob, $data);
    if ($ok === false) return $this->_setDbError('add data to');
    return true;
}

function close()
{
    if (!($e=$this->_firstUse())) return $e;
    if ($this->blob) {
        $id = @ibase_blob_close($this->blob);
        if ($id === false) return $this->_setDbError('close');
        $this->blob = null;
    } else {
        $id = null;
    }
    return $this->id ? $this->id : $id;
}

function length()
{
    if ($this->id === false) return 0; // wr-only blob
    if (!($e=$this->_firstUse())) return $e;
    $info = @ibase_blob_info($this->id);
    if (!$info) return $this->_setDbError('get length of');
    return $info[0];
}

function _setDbError($query)
{
    $hId = $this->id === null ? "null" : ($this->id === false ? "false" : $this->id);
    $query = "-- $query BLOB $hId"; 
    $this->database->_setDbError($query);        
}

// Called on each blob use (reading or writing).
function _firstUse()
{
    // BLOB is opened - nothing to do.
    if (is_resource($this->blob)) return true;
    // Open or create blob.
    if ($this->id !== null) {
        $this->blob = @ibase_blob_open($this->id);
        if ($this->blob === false) return $this->_setDbError('open'); 
    } else {
        $this->blob = @ibase_blob_create($this->database->link);
        if ($this->blob === false) return $this->_setDbError('create');
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Which i use like this:

```
 $text = new DBMgmt_Ibase_Blob($DB);
            if (!$text->write(htmlspecialchars($Data["Text"]))){
                throw new Exception("blob fail");
            }
  $blobid = $text->close();
  //similar query
$DB->query("INSERT INTO TABLE1 (BLOB_VALUE) VALUES (?)",$blobid);
```

After that in my database I find a number which I know I have to use with:

```
Blob = new DBMgmt_Ibase_Blob($DB,$data->Text);
    $data->Text = $Blob->read($Blob->length());
```

But i get  String is not a BLOB ID with a number in database like 30064771072.

I tried directly to add it but of course it does not work like this

```
$DB->query('insert into table (blob) values (?)',$string); // where string is like 170k chars
```

I get error of *Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Unexpected end of command - line 1, column 236*

I tryed putting it into file following php.net reference [php.net blob_import](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.ibase-blob-import.php) with code similar to this:

```
$dbh = ibase_connect($host, $username, $password);
$filename = '/tmp/bar';

 $fd = fopen($filename, 'r');
if ($fd) {

$blob = ibase_blob_import($dbh, $fd);
fclose($fd);

if (!is_string($blob)) {
    // import failed
} else {
    $query = "INSERT INTO foo (name, data) VALUES ('$filename', ?)";
    $prepared = ibase_prepare($dbh, $query);
    if (!ibase_execute($prepared, $blob)) {
        // record insertion failed
    }
}
} else {
// unable to open
```

But I am still getting result like the blob writing method.

Comment: no idea about firebird, but perhaps creating a file and importing that will work. It's a common aporach for large mysql queries (LOAD DATA INFILE)

Comment: Show some code you've tried, and the errors that you get. Also, a search for "Firebird PHP large queries" [turned this up as like the 4th hit.](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63214) What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Firebird should have an option to execute a SQL script, which is different than executing a query. You shouldn't have any issues executing the huge query as an SQL script.

Comment: the problem is i try to do it in php, i dont know why the question doesnt contain it when i wrote it, but its about php.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend In firebird 2.5 and earlier, maximum statement text length is 64 kilobytes, maximum total length for parameters is 32 kilobytes (where blobids are only 8 bytes)

Comment: "After that in my database I find a number which I know I have to use with" If this works depends on what you do exactly. There are two ids of a blob: one is the id pointing to the datapage in the database, and the other is the id you receive from a query and that is **valid only** in the current transaction. By the sound of it, you actually have inserting blobs working, it is selecting blobs that you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use parameters :

```
$query = ibase_prepare($DB, 'insert into table (blob) values (?)');
ibase_execute($query, $string);
```

cf : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-execute.php